# Why does .NET Core HttpClient or WebClient take so much longer than Python

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to retrieve content from a URL, I have tried .NET Core's HttpClient and WebClient, both of which take ~10 seconds to load this specific website.

However, when I use Python's urllib.request it loads within the same second. I have tried pretty much all the different combinations including: DownloadString, GetStringAsync, GetStreamAsync, GetAsync, OpenRead, etc.

I can provide the specific URL if needed. Any possible ideas?

Attempt #1

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream data = client.OpenRead("https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dtpp/search/");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
string s = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
data.Close();
reader.Close();
return s;
```

Attempt #2

```
using (var wc = new HttpClient())
        {
            var test = wc.GetAsync("https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dtpp/search/").Result;
            var contents = test.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return contents;
        }
```

Attempt #3

```
using (var wc = new HttpClient())
        {
            HTML = await wc.GetStringAsync("https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dtpp/search/");
            return HTML;
        }
```

All three attempts work, just take ~10 seconds everytime. If I run this the same sort of thing in Python it returns within the same second.

Python Version

```
with urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dtpp/search/') as response:
html = response.read()
```

Comment: Define slower, without code we cannot tell you.

Comment: Does Python automatically cache the response for you? Is it a big file that gzips really well? If Python enables gzip by default (don't know if it does) then this may be the reason since .NET won't.

Comment: Anyway, we need a [mcve] to be able to help you.

Comment: Let's throw a guess (without code who knows?): you are using async functions but using `.Result` which is temporarily deadlocking until one of the thread pool threads wakes up. Or perhaps you are downloading a huge string and not assigning a buffer of the right size upfront.

Comment: @Greg Added my code.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Added my code.

Comment: @Charlieface Added my code.

Comment: Use a tool such as Fiddler to intercept the requests and see if there is any difference. I can confirm the slowdown, but it seems to come from the server, so it is interpreting the request differently. A request in Firefox results in a gzip compression, you need to configure that, also use `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`. Neither of those options made significant difference though

Comment: @Charlieface I did try that HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead during my troubleshooting but it did not help. I'll try to see if there is a difference in the requests now.

Comment: Can you also add your Python code so we can compare?

Comment: @Charlieface I have the two different wireshark captures... One difference I notice is the .NET seems to be completing the request with TLS1.2 whereas Python is using TLS1.3. Earlier in my troubleshooting I did try to force my .NET code to use TLS1.3 but it would not and I read that's only available in Windows 11?

Comment: Itr is an interesting find. But how big is the data (thml) ?  Is it the same in both cases?

Comment: @HenkHolterman After converting the Python's byte string to a string they're just about the same, Python 77.7KB and .NET 76.5KB. Difference looks to be some extra spacing on the Python file.

Comment: I can confirm the ~10sec on dotnet core. In a Browser it loads instantly. It looks like deliberate throttling , the site is probably protected against DDOS and maybe scraping.

Comment: Have a look at the request headers, especially those coming from Python. Maybe you can copy those to dotnet.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Below are the request headers from Python:

    send: b'GET /air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dtpp/search/ 
    HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: www.faa.gov\r\nUser-Agent: 
    Python-urllib/3.10\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n'

See anything worth noting? What HTTP version does HttpClient use? 1.1?

Comment: If Henk's throttling  hypothesis is correct, you might want to try setting the User-Agent header on the C# version.

Comment: LOL. `httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", @"Python-urllib/3.10");` fixed it.

Comment: I had already tried one from a Browser but that did not work.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Wow...... Yup that indeed works. Thank you!

Comment: Also see: https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: Will do! @HenkHolterman